# Extract pattern in perl

Tags: regular-expression, perl, pattern-matching

Is it possible to have just one regex which can extract the pattern "**Mango-1.whatever..**" in any of these 3 conditions (i.e. $dummy). I keep printing everything after this pattern. If I use comma in the end, then it fails to print anything in CASE-2.

```
CASE-1: my $dummy = "Apple-1.fruit,Banana,Peach,Mango-1.Fruit";
OR
CASE-2: my $dummy = "Mango-1.Fruitssss";
OR
CASE-3: my $dummy = "Apple-1.fruit,Mango-1.Fruits,Orange-1.Fruit,Papaya";

$dummy =~ /(Mango-1.*),/i;
$dummy = $1;
chomp($dummy);

print "$dummy";
```

Comment: What exactly do you want as output? The "Mango-1.whatever" -- ending at the next comma, or to the end of the string?

Comment: The code you showed doesn't print anything for cases 1 and 2.

Comment: If you want the output `Mango-1.whatever..`, do `printf "%s\n" "Mango-1.whatever.."`.  If that’s not what you want, please do a better job of explaining what you want.  A table of sample inputs and corresponding expected outputs would be a great addition to your question. … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
$dummy =~ /(Mango-1[^,]*)/i;
```

i.e. Mango-1 plus anything that follows up to a comma or end of string.